# How to connect embedded solr with each other by sharding

Tags: solr, cluster-computing, solrj

I have been using sharding with multiple basic solr server for clustering. I also used one embedded solr server (Solrj Java API) with many basic solr servers and connecting them by sharding as embedded solr server is the caller of them. I used the code line below for this purpose.

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.set("shards", "solr1URL,solr2URL,...");
```

Now, I have many embedded solr servers running on different computers and they are unaware of each others. 
I want to communicate them with each other by sharding. Is it possible? if yes how? if not what are the other options that you can advice by using embedded solr servers?

Answer (score 3):

There is an open issue for that problem in Jira. See [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1858).